# Wordpress upload media tool double iframe? How to fix?

Tags: wordpress, thickbox

I'm using the WordPress upload media tool within my plugin and there's unusual error that is going on, I get two iframes that overlap. I searched online and there's not much info out there, one that made most sense was that thickbox was included twice and that's causing the problem, but within my plugin code I have it included only once.

This is the code I'm using to open the window:

`media-upload.php?type=image&TB_iframe=true&tab=library&width=640&height=640`

and when I take of "TB_iframe=true" then I see the two iframes under each other, otherwise they overlap, only see double titles.

And this is the PHP code:

```
if (isset($_GET['page']) && ($_GET['page'] == 'add_images' || $_GET['page'] == 'add_slides')) {

    add_action("admin_enqueue_scripts", "load_fixedly_media_upload_header");
}

function load_fixedly_media_upload_header() {

    wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
    wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
    wp_register_script('my-fixedly-upload', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/fixedly/scripts/admin.js', array('jquery','media-upload','thickbox'));
    wp_enqueue_script('my-fixedly-upload');
    wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');
}
```

Comment: btw if you'd like to look at the rest of the code you can download the WP plugin from here http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fixedly/

Comment: Can you check that you are correctly calling thickbox, e.g. with all the version paramters that are used in other location?